# Error on opening a URL in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am getting the below error while opening a URL in TortoiseSVN Repo-browser:

> Repository moved temporarily to '/oberr.cgi status 3d500 errmsg 3derrenginedown'; please relocate".

The URL was opening perfectly till yesterday. There seems to be no permission issues as well. Has anyone came across this error before? Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Reads like your Host is/was down.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once, they changed the address and you need to do just what the message says, check [this](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html) out, it explains how to realocate your working copy.